# Passing an integer or a type as a template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, metaprogramming

Here is an example case of what I'm trying to do (it is a "test" case just to illustrate the problem) :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <ratio>

template<int Int, typename Type> 
constexpr Type f(const Type x)
{
    return Int*x;
}

template<class Ratio, typename Type, 
         class = typename std::enable_if<Ratio::den != 0>::type>
constexpr Type f(const Type x)
{
    return (x*Ratio::num)/Ratio::den;
}

template</*An int OR a type*/ Something, typename Type>
constexpr Type g(const Type x)
{
    return f<Something, Type>(x);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout<<f<1>(42.)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<f<std::kilo>(42.)<<std::endl;
}
```

As you can see, there are two versions of the `f()` function : the first one takes an `int` as a template parameter, and the second one takes a `std::ratio`. The problem is the following :

I would like to "wrap" this function through `g()` which can take an `int` OR a `std::ratio` as first template parameter and call the good version of `f()`.

How to do that without writing two `g()` functions ? In other words, what do I have to write instead of `/*An int OR a type*/` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I would do it, but I've changed your interface slightly:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <ratio>

template <typename Type>
constexpr
Type
f(int Int, Type x)
{
    return Int*x;
}

template <std::intmax_t N, std::intmax_t D, typename Type>
constexpr
Type
f(std::ratio<N, D> r, Type x)
{
    // Note use of r.num and r.den instead of N and D leads to
    //   less probability of overflow.  For example if N == 8 
    //   and D == 12, then r.num == 2 and r.den == 3 because
    //   ratio reduces the fraction to lowest terms.
    return x*r.num/r.den;
}

template <class T, class U>
constexpr
typename std::remove_reference<U>::type
g(T&& t, U&& u)
{
    return f(static_cast<T&&>(t), static_cast<U&&>(u));
}

int main()
{
    constexpr auto h = g(1, 42.);
    constexpr auto i = g(std::kilo(), 42.);
    std::cout<< h << std::endl;
    std::cout<< i << std::endl;
}

42
42000
```

Notes:

1. I've taken advantage of `constexpr` to *not* pass compile-time constants via template parameters (that's what `constexpr` is for).
2. `g` is now just a perfect forwarder.  However I was unable to use `std::forward` because  it isn't marked up with `constexpr` (arguably a defect in C++11).  So I dropped down to use `static_cast<T&&>` instead.  Perfect forwarding is a little bit overkill here.  But it is a good idiom to be thoroughly familiar with.

Comment: On your edit: why not name your `std::ratio` parameter and use `r.num` and `r.den`? :)

Comment: Maybe also explain why you specifically use the members and not `N` and `D`, and not just have it in the edit history.

Answer (score 1):

> How to do that without writing two g() functions ?

You don't. There is no way in C++ to take either a type or a value of some type, except through overloading.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to have a template parameter taking both type and non-type values.

**Solution 1:**

Overloaded functions.

**Solution 2:**

You can store values in types. Ex:

```
template<int n>
struct store_int
{
    static const int num = n;
    static const int den = 1;
};

template<class Ratio, typename Type, 
         class = typename std::enable_if<Ratio::den != 0>::type>
constexpr Type f(const Type x)
{
    return (x*Ratio::num)/Ratio::den;
}

template<typename Something, typename Type>
constexpr Type g(const Type x)
{
    return f<Something, Type>(x);
}
```

But with this solution you will have to specify `g<store_int<42> >(...)` instead of `g<42>(...)`

If the function is small, I advise you to use overloading.

Comment: Solution 2 could just use `std::ratio`.

Comment: I agree with you for his example. But there are cases where it might be useful (ex: not `std::ratio` but another template that requires a lot of parameters).